# finding the solution for a specific integral

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I got confused, I haven't done calculus in a while... so I have this:
$$x(a) = x(0)+\int_0^a x(t) \,dt$$
also
$$x(t+dt)=x(t)+0.01*x(t)*dt$$
where dt in this case is for example 1 year
so
$$x(1)=x(0)+0.01*x(0)  $$
$$x(2)=x(1)+0.01*x(1)  $$
etc..

How do I obtain x(a)? Assuming I know a, for example a=10, and I also know x(0)=1000 for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if by $dt$ you mean a little variation in time then we have
$$\frac{x(t+h)-x(t)}{h}=\frac{x(t)}{100}$$ So taking limits both sides when $h\to 0$ then when get that $x'(t)=\frac{x(t)}{100}$. The solution to that differential equation is $x(t)=x(0)e^{t/100}$, if we assume that you are integrating between $0$ to $t$. So $$x(a)=x(0)e^{a/100}$$